# Assigning links having a certain word to an array using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I use Windows 10, iMacro 12.6.

I am new to iMacros. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I want to do something very simple but don't know how to do this.

I want to extract all the links having a certain word in a web page.

For example, I want to extract all the links having 'JCC' like:

1) http://**JCC**.domain-name.com/any_number_or_letter_or_whatever
  2) http://**JCC**.domain-name.com/any_number_or_letter_or_whatever
  3) http://**JCC**.domain-name.com/any_number_or_letter_or_whatever

... and so on

After extracting all the links above, I want to move to each web page one by one.

I mean, after visiting the first web page, I want do something, and then, I want to move to the 2nd web page, and then wait for 7 seconds, using 'WAIT SECONDS=7' command, to load the web page completely, and I want to do something... and so on.

I MUST NOT visit the web page I'd already paid a visit.

**Q1) How can I assign each link having a certain word to an array?
 Can I assign the links to an array AT RANDOM or FROM TOP TO BOTTOM as shown in the HTML page?**

**Q2) How can I move to each web page using the array variable?**

Sometimes, the web page doesn't show all the links having **JCCs**, so I have to hit the F5 key to reload the web page.

Sometimes I get nothing, sometimes 1 to 10 more new links.

**Q3) I want to add all the new links from the reloaded the web page, and then, assign them to the previous array. How can I do this?**

I don't know how many times I have to reload the web page but I guess 2 to 5 would be good within 5 minutes.

**Q4) I need to use this macro later in order to get some new links having JCCs. I MUST NOT visit the web page I'd already visited. How can I make iMacros do this?**

Thank you very much in advance. : )

BTW, I posted this at forum.imacros.net but it's not showing. : (